# Is it normal for some C expressions allowed in its grammar, not to be allowed when compiled in practice?

Tags: c, syntax, compilation, grammar

I was studying the C grammar: http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y-1999.html#unary-expression

There's this rule

```
assignment_expression
: conditional_expression
| unary_expression assignment_operator assignment_expression
;
```

And

```
unary_expression
: postfix_expression
| INC_OP unary_expression
| DEC_OP unary_expression
| unary_operator cast_expression
| SIZEOF unary_expression
| SIZEOF '(' type_name ')'
;
```

So why can't we do something like:

```
++v = 3<4 ? 10 : 2;
```

since ++v is an unary_expression?

Comment: The formal grammar doesn't define the language fully. There is a small set of additional requiremens written in English.

Comment: You are right. Those rules allow `++v =`. But see the note at the beginning of the file: _"I want to keep this version as close to the 1999 Standard C grammar as possible.._" which indicates it may not be a proper parser for the C language.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is normal. The C language is specified by several layers of rules. Roughly speaking, as an introduction:

- Individual characters are gathered into preprocessing tokens according to C’s lexical rules.
- The grammar specifies what sequences of preprocessing tokens are allowed as well as something of how they are interpreted (structured into a tree form).
- Constraints specified in the C standard add semantic rules that the grammar is incapable of specifying. For example, a constraint on the assignment operator is that it shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.
- Additional rules in the C standard specify semantics and additional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The language grammar is only one part of the language definition.  There are additional *semantic rules* and *constraints* that specify what syntax alone cannot.  For example, syntax alone cannot specify that variables and functions must be declared before use, or that the operand of the unary `*` operator must have a pointer type, etc.

There is a constraint on assignment expressions that the target of an assignment must be a *modifiable lvalue*, which is an expression that specifies a region of memory such that the contents of that region may be read or updated. If `v` is the name of a variable, then it also serves as an lvalue.

However, the semantic rules of the `++` operator state that the result of `++v` is *not* an lvalue, and as such cannot be the target of an assignment.

For chapter and verse on all of this, refer to the [C 2011 online draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), sections 6.3.2.1 (Lvalues, arrays, and function designators), 6.5.3 (Unary operators), and 6.5.16 (Assignment operators).